# How to convert military hours to mm/dd/yyyy and time in SQL sever?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a simple data set shown in Table 1 below. I would like to produce two new columns (`START_SHIFT_DT_TIME` and `END_SHIFT_DT_TIME`) using the columns from Table 1. The desired output is shown in Table 2.

The requirements are:

1. If the `START_SHIFT` hours starts on or after 22:00:00 then the actual start date is the previous day.
2. If the `START_SHIFT` hours starts before  22:00:00 then the actual start date is the following day.

I am using SQL server.

**Table 1**:

```
START_SHIFT END_SHIFT       DATE    
22:00:00    06:00:00        1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM
07:00:00    15:00:00        1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM
23:30:00    07:30:00        2/27/2012 12:00:00 AM
00:00:00    08:00:00        2/17/2012 12:00:00 AM
17:00:00    01:00:00        1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

**Table 2**:

```
START_SHIFT END_SHIFT     DATE                  START_SHIFT_DT_TIME     END_SHIFT_DT_TIME
22:00:00    06:00:00      1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM  1/12/2012 10:00:00 PM  1/13/2012 6:00:00 AM
07:00:00    15:00:00      1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM  1/13/2012 7:00:00 AM   1/13/2012 3:00:00 PM
23:30:00    07:30:00      2/27/2012 12:00:00 AM  2/26/2012 11:30:00 PM  2/27/2012 7:30:00 AM
00:00:00    08:00:00      2/17/2012 12:00:00 AM  2/17/2012 12:00:00 AM  2/17/2012 8:00:00 AM
17:00:00    01:00:00      1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM   1/1/2012 5:00:00 PM    1/2/2012 1:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Yes, SQL Server, but wich version? Also, if you have some working query please post it, does not matter is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution.

Comment: @ Yaroslav, Thanks for the advice. I use SQL Sever 05/08.

Comment: Then retag your question, add the needed ones ;)

Comment: @Yaroslav - You can make a suggested edit based on this info.

Comment: Is ther ea reason you don;t simply allow the start shift and end shift to both be of SQL Date Type (which includes the time in 24 hr format), and then let your application code deal with displaying startdate/Time and end date/time in the format of your choosing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  START_SHIFT,
  END_SHIFT,
  DATE,
  DATEADD(SS,
          DATEDIFF(SS,0,START_SHIFT),
          DATEADD(D,
                  CASE WHEN START_SHIFT >= '22:00' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END,
                  DATE)) START_SHIFT_DT_TIME,
  DATEADD(SS,
          DATEDIFF(SS,0,END_SHIFT),
          DATE) END_SHIFT_DT_TIME
FROM TBL
```

The pattern used in the last column is that the time component in `END_SHIFT` is converted to seconds and then added to the `DATE`.  In the 4th column, the same pattern is used and it goes through an additional step of adding -1 day (previous) when `START_SHIFT` is 22:00 or later.